# What is a kernel equivalent for ReadFileScatter/WriteFileGather

Tags: winapi, file-io, kernel-module

How to perform vectored file I/O from the Windows kernel? I need an equivalent of `ReadFileScatter`/`WriteFileGather`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NtReadFileScatter](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/File/NtReadFileScatter.html) and [NtWriteFileGatter](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/File/NtWriteFileGather.html) Also the [following](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=198306) might be a good addition

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `ZwReadFileScatter` and `ZwWriteFileGather` but I can't find documentation for them on MSDN, and I don't have the DDK headers at hand.